# Is $\lim_{b\to\infty} (x\log_b(x)) = 0$?

Tags: limits, logarithms

Is $$\lim_{b\to\infty} (x\log_b(x)) = 0$$?

I started to attempt this problem by graphing $y=x\log_2(x)$ and kept increasing the base of log to see what's the behaviour.

You can see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iamt46cuhq) that as the base becomes very very large, the curve tends to straighten out but still it isnt straightening out enough to say that it would become a straight line i.e y = 0.

Is that equation true? How do go on about it?

Comment: Note that $\log_b(x)=\ln(x)/\ln(b)$.

Comment: Note that $x \log_b x = x\ln x\cdot \tfrac{1}{\ln b}$

Comment: But $b>0$ and $b\ne 1$

Comment: Okay that was easy...

Answer (score 2):

We can use that $\log_AB=\frac{\log B}{\log A}$ therefore

$$x\log_bx=x\frac{\log x}{\log b}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact of logarithms that as $\log_BA = \frac{log A}{log B}$

then expression $\lim_{b \to \infty} x\log_b(x)$ can be rewritten as

$\lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{x\log x}{log b}$ and as $b \to \infty$ then $\log b \to \infty$ and hence making $\frac{1}{\log b} \to 0$ and in

$\lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{x\log x}{log b}$ b is the variable which is changing and hence making $x$ as constant and also $x\log x$ as

constant, so $\lim_{b \to \infty} x\log_b(x) = 0$